# proj.4 — problems to understanding the projection result

Tags: coordinate-system, proj4js, web-mercator

I am using pro4js for a webproject to project data obtained from the Openstreetmap database. Basically I have this code (javascript/ES 6):

```
const 
  //some coordinates
  we = {
    lon: 50.9802813,
    lat: 11.3290855
  },

  //the projectors 
  { forward, 
    reverse } = proj4('EPSG:3857')
;

let 
  [  lon1, 
     lat1  ] = forward([we.lon, we.lat]),

  [  lon2,
     lat2  ] = forward([we.lon + 1, we.lat + 1])
;

lon2 - lon1 = 111319.49079327378
lat2 - lat1 = 113736.3960447507
```

Why are those values this huge? What unit is that? Since these are projected coordinates they should represent coordinates on a flat 2d plane, don't they?

Comment: Unit is map meter, see http://epsg.io/3857.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @TomazicM this means that for those coordinates showed above, the distance from `lon1` to `lon2` represents `111319.49079327378` meters?

Comment: Yes. Since your distance is one degree difference and circle has 360 degrees, if you multiply distance by 360, you will get roughly 40.000 km, which is circumference of the Earth.

Comment: One more thing: Mercator map meters are not real meters (except on equator), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Scale_factor

Comment: @TomazicM thanx! I am aware of this....